# Light Table : parentheses are not auto-closing

Tags: lighttable, paredit

I'm trying to edit Clojure/ClojureScript files on Light Table with paredit, but the Plugin does not seem to work. When I open a parenthesis, it is not closed.

However the plugin is installed as shows the plugins list.

Have I missed some configuration step, or is it a bug?

(At the time of writing, I just installed the last version and have not touched the config).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since version 0.7.0, auto-closing parens are [no longer the default](https://github.com/LightTable/LightTable/blob/master/deploy/core/changelog.md#070), because of some issues with international keyboards apparently. It is mentioned in [this closed issue](https://github.com/LightTable/LightTable/issues/1759), as well as in the [FAQ](https://github.com/LightTable/LightTable/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-add-pair-keybindings).

What I needed to do was add this form to the `User behaviors` configuration:

```
[:app :lt.objs.settings/pair-keymap-diffs]
```

To do so, I followed these steps:

1. `Ctrl-Space` to open Commands
2. Type "user behaviors" and click the proposed command
3. This open a file that you can edit to add the above snippet.

Comment: Note for the "international" guys: at the time of writing (version, 0.7.2) this does not enable auto-closing for `{` and `[` characters, probably because you need to press another key (like ALT or MAJ) to type them. Reconfiguring my keyboard to US layout did it for me.

Answer (score 2):

Plugin only creates new commands and behaviors. You should configure `User keybindings` (Press `Ctrl+Space` and type `keybindings`) for the plugin like:

```
[:editor.clj "shift-alt-s" :paredit.select.parent]
[:editor.clj "cmd-shift-," :paredit.shrink.right]
[:editor.clj "alt-s" (:paredit.select.parent "(") :smart-indent-selection :paredit.select.clear]
[:editor.clj "cmd-shift-." :paredit.shrink.left]
[:editor.clj "cmd-shift-0" :paredit.grow.right]
[:editor.clj "alt-enter" (:paredit.select.parent "(") :eval-editor-form :paredit.select.clear]
[:editor.clj "cmd-shift-s" :paredit-plus.split-sexp]
[:editor.clj "cmd-shift-9" :paredit.grow.left]
[:editor.clj "cms-shift-j" :paredit-plus.join-sexps]
[:editor.clj "shift-alt-k" :paredit-plus.kill]
```

But paredit does not have effect on auto-closing of parens. It is default behavior of Light Table. Check `Default behaviors` if it contains this line:

```
[:editor :lt.plugins.auto-paren/close-pair]
```

Comment: It does contain this line.